# Parse a php array that has float index into new array

Tags: php

I have an array with float indexes that I'm getting from a plugin. I want to parse this array and take the ones that are float and put them in as a new array. Meaning what I have is

```
[1] => gsurvey128f54af2
[2] => gsurvey282bd4253
[5.1] => gsurvey5649a964f
[5.2] => gsurvey5fddb5e9f
[5.3] => gsurvey533c5b311
[5.4] => gsurvey5c8933efb
[5.5] => gsurvey5da48f59b
```

What I want is:

```
    [1] => gsurvey128f54af2
    [2] => gsurvey282bd4253
    [5] => array ( 
         [0] => gsurvey5649a964f
         [1] => gsurvey5fddb5e9f
         [2] => gsurvey533c5b311
         [3] => gsurvey5c8933efb
         [4] => gsurvey5da48f59b
)
```

I'm not clear on what's the best way to approach this.

Comment: Are you sure you have those keys for your array, because a float is an invalid key value

Comment: You may want to modify the code generating this interesting array to exactly what you have in your result. Floats are not valid.

Comment: They are actually strings.  Try a `var_dump`.

Comment: Floats as string will work.

Comment: This is coming from a wordpress plugin. That's the raw data I get. Even if I get it from database the arrays still contain floats. Somehow I want to combine floats for each into a new array.

Comment: The problem here is that you have an array of two types that can easily cause a problem. What if you have an index of "7" so you make index [7] a string. Then, you have an index of "7.1" so you try to set the value of index [7][0], but [7] is not an array, so referring to [0] is invalid. Are you positive that this situation will not occur?

Answer (score 1):

I made the comment above that this problem is very prone to error because it is possible to have input that would set a single value to be both a string and an array at the same time. That will obviously fail. Assuming that the input is clean...

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $key=>$val)
{
  $a = explode('.', $key);
  if(sizeof($a)==2)
  {
    if(!isset($new_array[$a[0]])) $new_array[$a[0]] = array();
    $new_array[$a[0]][] = $val;
  }
  else $new_array[$key]=$val;
}
```

Comment: That worked. It does leave an extra blank index at end of each one but I can debug it at this point. Thank you.

Comment: I tested it using the example array from your question and I do not see a blank index. I am not sure where it may come from. Perhaps you could drop the "isset" check to ensure that $a[0] key is set. That is there just to help newer programmers read the code. PHP creates the key in the next line if it doesn't exist. So, the code works fine without it.

Comment: That was due to some blank in my form so the code you put works great.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, this should work:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if(count($i = explode('.', $k)) > 1) {
        $result[$i[0]][] = $v;
    } else {
        $result[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to leave constructive criticism?

Comment: Your code does not handle the cases where there is no '.' in the key. The request is that those are mapped to the new array as is.

Comment: Damn, I tested in my IDE and never edited the answer.  Edited, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Example with [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$array = array (
    '1' => 'gsurvey128f54af2',
    '2' => 'gsurvey282bd4253',
    '5.1' => 'gsurvey5649a964f',
    '5.2' => 'gsurvey5fddb5e9f',
    '5.3' => 'gsurvey533c5b311',
    '5.4' => 'gsurvey5c8933efb',
    '5.5' => 'gsurvey5da48f59b'
);

$output = array();
array_walk( $array, function( $item, $key ) use ( &$output ) {
    $keys = explode( '.', $key );
    isset( $keys[1] ) ? $output[ $keys[0] ][ $keys[1] ] = $item : $output[ $keys[0] ] = $item;
});

print_r( $output );
/*
Array
(
    [1] => gsurvey128f54af2
    [2] => gsurvey282bd4253
    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => gsurvey5649a964f
            [2] => gsurvey5fddb5e9f
            [3] => gsurvey533c5b311
            [4] => gsurvey5c8933efb
            [5] => gsurvey5da48f59b
        )

)
*/
```